# cart becomes empty in Gocart (CI)

Tags: codeigniter, cart

I am using Gocart CI for my e-commerce website.I have completed my work and my website is ready but I am facing a problem and I am not able to figure it out.And this problem is so big.

Problem is -

Sometime my cart becomes empty when I refresh or I go for make payment.And sometimes it makes me logout so cart automatically becomes empty.

I also don't know in which case it is happening.It does not happen always , it happens suddenly at any time.

I thought may be it is because of any session but if it is a session problem then it should get blank at some particular time but sometimes it becomes empty as I add to cart and go for checkout and in some case I stay idle and refresh then it becomes empty.

Guys Please help me as it is most important for any e-com that it's cart should not be empty in any case.

Please Please help.

Comment: the problem that you describe usually arise because of session. by default Go cart uses database for session. Check the DB for sessions. see if the cart data is present in session table. Or try to change `$config['sess_expiration']`

Comment: @JunaidAtique but it must be for cart right. But in some case I get logged out why it is that.And also if it's a session problem the let's say I have set session time for 20 minutes then it must empty the cart after 20 minutes on each time but now it is doing it sometimes in 2 minute sometimes after 30 minutes and sometimes keep it going without empty. Can you please explain brother.It would be a big big help.Thanks

Comment: check if your go cart is using CI session or PHP Native session. On github they have replaced the CI session with PHP Native session because of this issue.
https://github.com/gocart/GoCart

Comment: This is probably a session re-generation issue, you'll either have to check github to see if there's a fix for this, or pick up the changes for sessions in CI 3 to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your cart content is too big check you session limit